# Actually finding the limiting floor in the generalised egg drop puzzle?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

The problem is this:

Given a n-floor building, k eggs, what is the minimum floor from which if you throw eggs they'll break?

I've gotten to finding the actual optimal number of trials, using dynamic programming and this recursive formulation:

```
t(floors,eggs) = 1 + min( max(t(i-1,eggs-1)), t(floors-i,eggs))) 
where i goes from 1 to floors.
```

But I'm no closer to finding the actual strategy to use to find the critical floor in minimum trials.

Comment: Know how to recover a shortest path from s to t after using Bellman-Ford or Dijkstra to find single-source shortest-path distances in a graph?  It's exactly the same thing here; your graph is just the set of `(f, e)` pairs connected by edges labelled by `i`.

Comment: I guess dynamic programming would be a bad choice to solve `egg-floor` problem!

Comment: @tmyklebu I guess you mean finding the shortest path from (f,e) to one of the base cases. But Dijkstra already takes O(V^2) time, and that gives me O(f*e*f*e) time, which is really really bad.

Comment: @shekhar suman What do you suggest?

Comment: @j_random_hacker floors and eggs. Edited the question.

Comment: Thanks.  You don't need to *run* Dijkstra -- all tmyklebu means is that, associated with each pair (floors, eggs) there is not only the value of the function t(floors, eggs), but *also* the value(s) of i which enabled the function to achieve that (i.e. its minimum possible) value.  You can record these in an auxiliary array indexed by (floors, eggs) as you go.

Comment: What I mean is that your DP solution *is* an implementation of Bellman-Ford.  You can either do as j_random_hacker says and keep track of the back edges in your shortest path tree or you can just work it out from the shortest path distances you computed.

Comment: @hoodakaushal- j_random_hacker has already given the hint!

Comment: @j_random_hacker Oh, yeah that could work. I would have to handle off-sets etc to get the exact values, but yeah, thanks!

Comment: @tmyklebu How would I compute it only from the shortest path distances? Because that would be better than keeping an auxiliary matrix.